# Laços de repetição for e while javascript

Tags: javascript, lógica

Eu estava a fazer exercícios para melhorar minha lógica e reparei que não consigo fazer decremento utilizando o loop while?

````
cont = 20

while(cont > 20){
cont -= 1
console.log(cont)

```
sempre me retorna undefined, gostaria de saber o porque, já que se eu tentar fazer um incremento eu consigo com sucesso!!

outra questão usando o operador for

```
var array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','x','z']

for(var i= 0; i < array.length; i++){
    console.log(`${i} letra ${array.length[i]}`)
}

saida:
1 letra undefined
2 letra undefined
3 letra undefined
4 letra undefined
5 letra undefined
6 letra undefined
7 letra undefined
8 letra undefined
9 letra undefined
// .....

o operador for percorre o array e me retorna a quantidade de índices do array, mas não o valor... como faria para ter o valor retornado juntamente com o indice?
````

Comment: Não coloque cumprimentos ou agradecimentos nas perguntas. Se tiver que colocar algo fora do escopo técnico use os comentários. Ref-> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

o problema com o while é que a condição nunca é verdadeira, ai o loop nunca chega a rodar.

como  count começa com 20, e comparar se é menor que 20, isso é falso.

---

sobre o for, você precisa imprimir a posição:

```
console.log(`${i} letra ${array[i]}`)
```

e não:

```
console.log(`${i} letra ${array.length[i]}`)
```

Comment: muito obrigado quanto ao while eu conseguir o resultado que gostaria usando DO/WHILE